# Divide by zero exception of average of columns in a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, average, divide-by-zero

I have some code made for calculate the average of a row in a table. The problem is now that the sum of `MinTwee`, `MinEen`, `nul`, `PlusEen` and `PlusTwee` *(are column names)* is equal to zero, it gives me a divide by zero exception *(what is normal of course)*. How can you protect it that it given't that? I will that if the sum is equal to zero the average is also equal to zero of that row. I use SQL server 2014.

```
select top 5 
    id, mintwee, mineen, nul, pluseen, plustwee, naam
from 
    topic 
where 
    CategorieID = 7 and verwijderd = 0 
order by 
    round(cast((mintwee * (-2) + mineen * (-1) + nul * 0 + pluseen * 1 + PlusTwee * 2) as float) / (MinTwee + MinEen + nul + PlusEen + PlusTwee), 1) desc, creatie desc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  test for 0 value with a case when

```
select top 5 id, mintwee, mineen, nul, pluseen, plustwee, naam
from topic 
where CategorieID = 7 and verwijderd = 0 
order by 
   case when (MinTwee + MinEen + nul + PlusEen + PlusTwee) = 0 then  creatie
   else
   round(cast((mintwee * (-2) + mineen * (-1) + nul * 0 + pluseen * 1 + PlusTwee * 2) as float) / (MinTwee + MinEen + nul + PlusEen + PlusTwee), 1)
   end
    desc, 
   creatie desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to avoid an error is `nullif()`:

```
order by 
    coalesce(round(cast((mintwee * (-2) + mineen * (-1) + nul * 0 + pluseen * 1 + PlusTwee * 2) as float) /
          nullif(MinTwee + MinEen + nul + PlusEen + PlusTwee, 0), 1), 0) desc,
    creatie desc
```

Comment: I have try your query but if the sum is zero, if gives `null` (not the number) and that is not what I will have.

Comment: @Hein . . . Normally, in these circumstances, the best value is `NULL`, but if you want 0, then use `COALESCE()`.